# Store email variable for insertion in block?

Tags: global-variable

I want something like this in a CMS block:

```
<a href="mailto:{{url:store1-general-email}}">Send an email</a>
```

...which should result with a proper insertion of the General Email account for store1

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: I didn't try anything... I searched like crazy but only got hits on transactional email template variables. Maybe there is a canonical list of Magento variables somewhere, but I could not locate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{config path="trans_email/ident_support/email"}}

<a href="mailto:{{config path="trans_email/ident_support/email"}}">{{config path="trans_email/ident_support/email"}}</a>
```

I figured it out, thanks to Manish Prakash for his blog post, [Advanced Transactional Email Templates](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/25/magento-advanced-transactional-email-templates/)

One more beautiful thing that I discovered on this search is an amazing plugin that allows you to very easily create complex custom directives, the [Aoe_ExtendedFilter](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_ExtendedFilter) maintained by Lee Saferite. Very nice indeed.